# Why does this particular meta question redirects me to the error page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

I am getting an error message when I click on the question [Copy code from Stackoverflow posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100721/copy-code-from-stackoverflow-posts) on meta. I am able to navigate to other questions on meta without any issues.

[image: Question]

[image: Error]

Comment: I'm told devs are looking into it. It was [migrated from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921755/copy-code-from-stackoverflow-posts?noredirect=1); I'm guessing something went wrong with that

Comment: The actual error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It's a duplicate too, meh.

Comment: @Tim If only we could close it :). Maybe it's a defense mechanism

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I like to think of it as the system auto-closing the question for us, by making it inaccessible to everyone.

Comment: Also, searching for "Copy code stackoverflow" causes the 500 on the results page. The plot thickens...

Comment: @Michael: Is it possible for a question to have 1 view and 1 answer? I thought the first view of the question is by OP when they submit the question. In the first screenshot, it shows 1 view and 1 answer. There were no answers on SO. Just curious.

Comment: @Siva The view counting is pretty weird, and the question list is cached anyway, so it can show old data. Between those two anything can happen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bug was introduced in the anonymous gravatar render - it's been fixed.